# The designView of my content_main.xml is not displayed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

even i resynced the gradle,i still cant see the design view.it happens with all projects,Even i started a totaly new project and it has the same problem

**picture of Errors :**

[image: picture of Errors]

Errors:
1)Render problem: failed to find style 'coordinateLayoutStyle' in current theme.

2)Using private resources: The resources @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour is marked as private in com.android.support.design .

3) Missing styles: Missing styles, is the correct theme chosen for this layout?

4) Failed to instantiate one or more classes: The following classes could not be instantiated:
-android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
-android.support.design.widget.AppbarLayout

Comment: Please provide error messages as text, so they can be found by text searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,Actually there is a problem with SDK 28.

**Solution:**
Use SDK version 27 i.e in your "*build.gradle(Module:app)*" and change

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

**TO:**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**Also use these Dependencies versions:**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

This will solve the issue,but it will still show an
**Rendering Problem:Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme**
To solve this issue write this into **application theme**

```
<style name="Apptheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

Hope so that will help you!